Trying to figure out how to biuld flask page but get lost there
Want to practice a bit with flask, trying to make a hidden interests extractor from meta.
But getting lost while trying to show table on a page with all interests were find after search.
I can't show it in a different pages, all results shows on the same page and super hard to read :)
Here is a python flask app:
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for
from meta_hidden_interests_extractor import get_hidden_interests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    search_key = request.args.get('search_key', '')
    page = int(request.args.get('page', 1))
    per_page = 100

    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_key = request.form['search_key']
        return redirect(url_for('index', search_key=search_key, page=1))

    if not search_key:
        return render_template('index.html', search_key=search_key, page=page, total_pages=0, data=[])

    data = get_hidden_interests(search_key, page, per_page)

    total_items = len(data)
    total_pages = (total_items // per_page) + (1 if total_items % per_page > 0 else 0)

    return render_template('index.html', data=data, search_key=search_key, page=page, total_pages=total_pages)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5100)

Here is HTML template:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Meta Hidden Interests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Enter Search Key for Meta Hidden Interests</h1>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="search_key" placeholder="Enter search key" value="{{ search_key }}" required>
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>

        {% if data %}
        <div class="table-container">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Audience</th>
                        <th>Path</th>
                        <th>Topic</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for item in data %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.audience }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.path }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.topic }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="pagination">
            {% if page > 1 %}
            <a href="?page={{ page - 1 }}&search_key={{ search_key }}"><button>Previous</button></a>
            {% endif %}
            <span>Page {{ page }} of {{ total_pages }}</span>
            {% if page < total_pages %}
            <a href="?page={{ page + 1 }}&search_key={{ search_key }}"><button>Next</button></a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <p>No data available. Please enter a search key and try again.</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>

I tryied to create pagination, but withut success. Never work with flask before. Super low skill in python as well :)
Still learning.
GPT halped me a lot, but can't sovle exact this issue. He offer me thousand variants of code, but non of them works as expected.

The flask app would show every items in your data (returned by get_hidden_interests) because you pass the whole object to the template. If you only want to show part of it, you should either 1. only retrieve part of data in get_hidden_interests (which is common practice, often done with database) or 2. only takes a slice out of all the data before passing to render_template

Actually I feel confused about how you implemented get_hidden_interests. Judging from the parameters it seems you already took the correct slice in that functions, but from what infers from total_items and total_pages it seems you didn't. Maybe check the value of data by logging it directly into terminal.

thank you so much for feedback.
Did some changes, which took me a while and got results as expected.

Glad you solved the problem. Since my comments seem to have answered your question, I rewrite it formally to an answer like common stackoverflow practice

The {% for %} block of flask template would iterate over every item in your data (returned by get_hidden_interests) as is, so it's your task to prepare the correct data. Judging from the meaning of total_items and total_pages you might have mistakenly pass the whole database to it, instead of only required page of it. And get_hidden_interests accepting page and per_page feels like it should do the job, so there might be errors there.
